# My Window in NetBeans Doesn't Pop Up After Running

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, interface, window

```java
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author User
 */
public class menuPrincipal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form menuPrincipal
     */
    public menuPrincipal() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/LOGO MERCADO MORAES.png"))); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("jLabel2");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(136, 136, 136)
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 222, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(140, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addGap(0, 159, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        getContentPane().add(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setBounds(0, 0, 498, 368);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(menuPrincipal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(menuPrincipal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(menuPrincipal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(menuPrincipal.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new menuPrincipal().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Post properly formatted code. Code does NOT have "bullets".

Comment: (1-) An image is NOT code. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. We should be able to copy/paste/compile and test the code you post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Class names should start with an upper case character. All the classes in the JDK follow this standard. Learn by example.
2. Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Most of the code you posted is related to using the GroupLayout. Setting the layout null overrides all the code. Also, then is no need for using setBounds(...), since that is the job of the layout manager.

Comment: i'm a begginer so, what should do if the code was already made like this, i mean i just putted a named and created a jframeform, i learned how to use eclipse but it just doesn't pup up my windows anyways i don't know what to do

Comment: I already suggested what to do. The window displays, but all you see is a small title bar for the frame. Delete the statement that set the null layout.